# If Set Batch error

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, set

I'm trying to use `SET /p` for for a simple yes/no scenario but my syntax seems to be all screwy:

```
SET /p var="Knock Knock! "
IF NOT %VAR% == "Who is there" (ECHO "NOPE")
SET /p var="Orange! "
IF NOT %VAR% == "Orange who?" (ECHO "NOPE)
ECHO "Orange you glad I didn't say banana?"
```

Sorry to waste your time with a simple question

Comment: your second `ECHO "NOPE` is missing its closing quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *quote* variables containing spaces, such as with:

```
IF NOT "%VAR%"=="Who is there" ECHO "NOPE"
```

Otherwise, it translates into:

```
IF NOT Who is there=="Who is there" ECHO "NOPE"
```

and complains about the `is`.

---

Making that change, and a couple of other improvements, would result in something like:

```
    @echo off
:loop1
    set /p var=Knock Knock! 
    if not "%var%"=="Who is there?" (
        echo Please answer 'Who is there?'
        goto :loop1
    )
:loop2
    set /p var=Orange! 
    if not "%var%" == "Orange who?" (
         echo Please answer 'Orange who?'
         goto :loop2
    )
    echo Orange you glad I didn't say banana?
```

and running it thus:

```
C:\USERS\paxdiablo\Documents> kkjoke
Knock Knock! What?
Please answer 'Who is there?'
Knock Knock! NO!
Please answer 'Who is there?'
Knock Knock! Who is there?
Orange! Oh, is it 'orange of steak knives at half price'?
Please answer 'Orange who?'
Orange! What about 'orange, orange, my kingdom for orange'?
Please answer 'Orange who?'
Orange! Well, IS IT?
Please answer 'Orange who?'
Orange! Orange who?
Orange you glad I didn't say banana?
```